# $f(x) = \frac {e^{2x-1}} {(1+e^{2x-1})}. $ What is the value of $ f(1/2009) + f(2/2009) + ... + f(2008/2009) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Here's the question.

Let $f(x) = \frac {e^{2x-1}} {(1+e^{2x-1})}$

Then what is the value of $ f(1/2009) + f(2/2009) + ... + f(2008/2009) $ ?

All I could think of doing was to add and subtract 1 in the numerator of the function, to get the value of the sum as 2008 - {something}.

Hints??

**EDIT**:
please note the correction. $f(x) = \frac {e^{2x-1}} {(1+e^{2x-1})}$ and NOT $ \frac {e^{2x-1}} {(1-e^{2x-1})}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $f(x) + f(1-x)$.

Comment: Got the answer! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Great Hint! +1...

Comment: @CalvinLin If you don't mind me asking, what is the difference between brilliant.org and sites such as art of problem solving?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to just bring about a curiosity, now that we have Calvin's very clever observation that leads to the exact result.  But the sum looks a lot like a Riemann sum to me, so I went forth:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2008} f\left(\frac{k}{2009}\right) \approx 2009 \int_0^1 dx \: f(x)$$

Note of course that the sum on the LHS goes from $k=0$, and not $k=1$ as specified in the OP.  Keep that in mind.

So the integral is easily evaluated:

$$\int_0^1 dx \: f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \log{\left(\frac{1+e}{1+(1/e)}\right)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2008} f\left(\frac{k}{2009}\right) \approx \frac{2009}{2}$$

But as I included the $k=0$ term in this sum, let's subtract it out to get the correct approximation:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2008} f\left(\frac{k}{2009}\right) \approx \frac{2009}{2} - \frac{1}{1+e}$$

The exact value of the sum is $1004$, from which the above approximate result has a relative error of

$$\frac{e}{2 (1+e) 2008} \sim 0.02\%$$

Just saying.